# What metals will redirect/focus a magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields

I would like to know what metals can redirect a magnetic field and what shape would the metals most concentrate the field. I've heard that an iron cone/dome will increase the density of the field, and lower the area that the field reaches.
What metal is most effective at redirecting/focusing the field and what shape works best?

Comment: Mu-metals might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes, there is no shield or substance that will effectively block magnetic fields as such. You can however redirect the magnetic field lines, which is what some people call magnetic shielding.

Mu-metal is a nickel–iron soft ferromagnetic alloy with very high permeability, which is used for shielding sensitive electronic equipment against static or low-frequency magnetic fields. It has several compositions. One such composition is approximately 77% nickel, 16% iron, 5% copper and 2% chromium or molybdenum.
Mu-metal - Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu-metal